# How to index rows in csv files and take columns as arguments?

Tags: python

Here is a sample of my csv file:

```
Date       Open    High    Low    Close
9/2/2021   34.05   40.34   33.03  36.7
9/3/2021   35.9    41.98   34.9   36.89
```

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import csv

def StockMarket():
    while True:
       command = input('$')
       if command.lower() == 'quit':
           break
       elif command.lower() == 'readfiles':
           mrna_data,pfe_data =    
ReadFiles('MRNA.csv.numbers','PFE.1.csv')
    #elif command.lower() = 'pricesondate'
        

def ReadFiles(MRNA,PFE):
    file = open(MRNA,'r', newline = '')
    reader = csv.reader(file,delimiter ='\t')
    next(reader)
    mrna_data = []
    for row in reader:
        #index rows only need row 0 and 4th row
        mrna_data.append(row)
    reader.close()

    file = open(PFE,'r', newline = '')
    reader = csv.reader(file,delimiter ='\t')
    next(reader)
    pfe_data = []
    for row in reader:
        pfe_data.append(row)
    reader.close()

    return mrna_data,pfe_data
```

I want to index rows 0 and 4 since they are the only rows I'm using. Then I would like to use row 0 as an argument in "YYYY-MM-DD" format which would then return me the corresponding row 4(This would be a separate function).
I've tried doing multiple methods from examples online and such but none of them work. If someone could help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It'd be easier to put the csv in a pandas dataframe but I don't see how you would get row 4 from row 0 with the csv example you've provided. Are you trying to match rows between the two csv files?

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty with and what result are you hoping to get?  Just saying something does not work is too vague, please show your work and the specific issue(s) you ran into.  Please also update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including sample input and expected output.